# How to add ('@loc1','@loc2') in ISNULL with variables having commas

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two nvarchar values from passing from the Stored procedure.
@loc1 and @loc2
**If loc1 is NULL then I need to use loc2 in the where condition.
Otherwise loc1**

**Consider the Values @loc1=NULL and @loc2=B,C
Here i need to use @loc2 in the "where" condition
Consider the Values @loc1=A and @loc2=B,C
Here i need to use @loc1**

My query will look like this,

```
select * from t_table where type in (ISNULL(@loc1,@loc2))
```

Here when @loc1 is become null the @loc2 used in the condition

```
select * from t_table where type in (B,I)
```

How to solve this issue without writing a function?

Comment: if `@loc2` is equal to `B,C` then, in common with most languages, SQL will treat that as a *single* string that *happens* to contain a comma, not as *multiple* separate values. You can find plenty of examples for how to split that data up by searching for `SQL Server split commas`, but ideally, save yourself the work and use a datatype *designed* for holding multiple values, such as table-valued parameters or xml.

Comment: Then, separately, you probably ought to go and read Erland Sommarskog's [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: I had already made this with Splitting technique.But i want it in a simple manner